# ConnectException when connecting to server on VM

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a chat app in Java, but there's one thing in my way.
When I start my server on the vm(which is in NAT mode), the server gives no errors. But when I try to join with the client (on the host pc), I get a Connect Exception.
I've disabled the firewall on the vm, port forwarded the vm (learned that [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/vmware/allow-access-to-a-vmware-virtual-machinenat-from-another-computer/)) so that I can connect to port 9010 on the vm using localhost(on host pc) and port 9011, checked the code, and everything seems to be good (which is not, otherwise I wouldn't have errors).

Code of the server (at the connecting part) [here](https://pastebin.com/wXZg9r9M) (pastebin because I can't copy/paste from vm to host pc)

Code of the client(also at the connecting part):

```
try {

        socket = new Socket("localhost", 9011); //line 25 in the file

        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String msg = in.readLine();
        chatWindow.writeToChat(msg);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Stack:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at com.tomvos.dev.chatclient.Client.<init>(Client.java:25)
at com.tomvos.dev.chatclient.Client.main(Client.java:44)
```

All help is welcome ;)

Comment: Do you have the entire stack trace for this?

Comment: @Perimosh Adding it now

Comment: "*Connection refused*" -- That means it is in *all* likelyhood a network configuration error. You may want to try if you can connect with `telnet` before debugging your program.

Comment: Also, you'll probably save yourself trouble if you start off trying to run the server on the same system as the client, so as to avoid potential network configuration problems.

Comment: telnet doesn't connect either...

Comment: I'm going to try to put it on the host pc

Comment: Also, try using the IP for NAT, and not localhost.